# How can I change the default commentator name in Adobe Acrobat XI Pro?

Tags: adobe-acrobat

How can I change the default commentator name in Adobe Acrobat XI Pro?

[image]

Changing my name in the `identity` form in the preferences didn't help, and my login name is grayed out:

[image]

The option `make current property default` didn't work neither:

[image]

I am aware that I could select all the comments and change the author:

[image]

but I would prefer to change the default behavior to avoid forgetting changing the author of some comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using DC, but think the process is the same for XI. In Edit > Preferences > Commenting, uncheck the box for Always use Log-in Name for Author name. Now you can go the Make Current Properties Default path you tried earlier. It will stick between documents.

[image]